# How to call a funtion passed as prop in child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-proptypes

I'm passing a function as a prop to a child component and I need to call that function when I click on a button (in the child component) but the function never gets called.

I've tried to call the prop that contain the funtion as a function, like `this.props.nameOfTheProp();` but this doesn't work.

**Father Component**

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.triggerMatchesToAcceptUpdate = this.triggerMatchesToAcceptUpdate.bind(this);
  }

  triggerMatchesToAcceptUpdate() {
    this.props.getMatchesToAccept();
  }

  render() {
    return() {
      <div>
        <MatchesToAccept triggerUpdate={this.triggerMatchesToAccept}/>
      </div>
    }
  }
}

Dashboard.propTypes = {
  getMatchesToAccept: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default connect(null, { getMatchesToAccept })(Dashboard);
```

**Child Component**

```
class MatchesToAccept extends Component {
  acceptMatch() {
    //This function gets call on click but no the one that comes from props
  }

  render() {
    return() {
      <button
        onClick={() => { this.props.triggerUpdate(); this.acceptMatch() }}
      >Accept</button>
    }
  }
}

export default connect(null, {})(MatchesToAccept);
```

When I clicked on the button in the Child component only `acceptMatch()` gets called but it should be the two functions.

Comment: What do you mean it's not called? How does `acceptMatch()` is called if triggerUpdate doesn't when it's executed after. P.s. You don't have to make a function that calls both, you already have it as arrow function

Comment: looks nothing wrong with your code while passing and executing the function can you place a debugger inside your function and open console and look if it is called or not.

Comment: Am I seeing wrong? There isn't a method name as `triggerMatchesToAccept`. Isn't it `triggerMatchesToAcceptUpdate`?